# Unable to deploy MobileFirst app to MobileFirst container on Bluemix via MobileFirst CLI

Tags: java, android, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

As per https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/08/14/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-server-bluemix-net-5-minutes/

When I try to deploy a locally developed MobileFirst app to MobileFirst container on `Bluemix` via MobileFirst CLI, I keep getting below error:

Couldn't connect to server `BluemixServer` at `http://x.x.x.x:9080.
failed to retrieve runtime information: Unexpected token E: HTTP 404 - Not Found`

Here's what I'm passing as parameters:

1. Enter name of new server definition: BluemixServer
2. Enter the fully qualified URL of this server: http://***.***.***.***:9080 (Bluemix public URL of MFP server container)
3. Enter the MFP admin login id: admin
4. Enter the MFP admin password: *****
5. Save admin password for this server?: Yes
6. Enter the context root of the MobileFirst administration services: MobileFirstStarter

I think problem is with "parameter 1" above: I tried passing it as both `BluemixServer` as well as the IBM container name for `MobileFirst` image that I created but it fails with same error in both cases.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Show the full steps, from adding the server to trying to push it and the failure you get. all of it.

Comment: BluemixServer is only a definition name. The most likely cause of the error should be point 6. Are you sure "MobileFirstStarter" is the context root of admin services ? It is normally worklightadmin or wladmin ( if you have not changed it yourself). Can you verify this?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Vivin, the issue is probably for sure step 6.

"MobileFirstStarter" is the name of the image used for the container. That's fine. But the value that should be used in step 6 is "worklightadmin", like in the example given in the blog post linked to in the question.